# Live backup solutions for Ubuntu? Preferably to Google Drive?

Tags: backup, sync

In my company, we use Windows. **All work** (all!) is done in Google Drive, since Google made a synchronization tool for Windows called Google Drive Backup and Sync. **Everything** is saved there, all the files you work on, everything you download from the net, and everything is sync'ed to Google Drive on the fly. It's fast and transparent.

Now, since I've switched to Ubuntu, I'm having a lot of trouble sharing documents and collaborating with colleagues on documents. I've been given the advice to run `google-drive-ocamlfuse` - it does the job, but it's *extremely* slow. Descending into a subfolder, it can easily take 2-5 minutes to get the directory listing.

This is a very serious problem for me.

The obvious solution is to go back to using windows. I'd *hate* that.

I know Dropbox is another option, but I would have to synchronize Dropbox with my Google Drive then. Also, it's not free if you want more than a few GB.

I could work on a local drive in my house, but that wouldn't work when I'm at work. And vice versa.

I'm running out of ideas, and my colleagues and my sysadm are running out of patience with me. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yeah, well, that thread is from 2012 - I was wondering if something might have changed during the past seven years ;-)

Comment: I'm using Grive with Grive Tools with Google Drive, they work stable on my MATE (so I have used my [own instruction](https://askubuntu.com/a/1012861/66509)). It is bad that official Google position [did not changed](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2375082?hl=en) - "Linux: Backup and Sync isn't currently available using the Linux operating system. You can use Google Drive on the web at drive.google.com".

Comment: If your livelihood is at stake, then it may be worthwhile to adhere to the workplace standards. Many of us use both Ubuntu and Windows daily at work.